# Is it possible to create threads in multiple files to be executed in main file?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

I have the following structure to want to interact with a sorter (infinite loop) and networker (infinite loop) on 2 separate threads. The threads are generated in each of their respective files instead of the main file. Are there any issues with this?

main.c

```
int main(void {
   network();
   sorter();
}
```

sort.c // creates random array then sorts them in a continuous while loop (never ending)

```
void sorter() {
    int r1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, (void *) &sorter, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
}

int* getArray() { ... }
int getElement() { ... }
```

network.c

```
void network() {
   int r2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, (void *) &startNetwork, NULL);
   pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
}

void startNetwork() {
  int sockfd, portno, optval, n;
  socklen_t adSize;
  struct sockaddr_in servAd, clientAd;
  ...
  while(1) { 
    //receive packet 
   int *arr = getArray();
   // send packets
   // or receive packet that has a command to get array 
  }

}
```

Is it possible to have the threads structured like that? Will my main file freeze because the thread is not being created in the main file? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You don't create threads in *files*, you create them in a *process* during execution. The source code containing calls to `pthread_create` is not relevant at runtime

Answer (score 2):

The main issues with `sorter()` are (1) that it won't return until the thread function returns, and (2) the thread function is `sorter()`, so you have an indefinite loop.  This is likely a problem with trying to abstract your code into the question.  There are nitty-gritty details to fix up like the types of the functions, etc.

The issues with `network()` might be similar or different; you've not shown the function you call from `main()`, so it is not clear what you intend.  The code in `networker()` is not good; it makes `pthread_create()` call a function with an incorrect signature — thread functions should have the signature `void *function(void *arg);`.

However, in general, there is no problem with starting different threads in code from different source files.  If the threads are not detached — if you're going to join them — then you'll need to make the `pthread_t` initialized by `pthread_create()` available for the code that manages the joining — possibly because they're in global variables or part of a global array, or possibly because you provide functional access to private data stored in the separate source files.

So, you might have:

**`network.c`**

```
static pthread_t thread2;

static void *network_thread(void *arg);

void network(void)
{
    if (pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, network_thread, NULL) != 0)
        …handle error…
}

void network_join(void)
{
    void *vp = 0;
    if (pthread_join(&thread2, &vp) != 0)
        …report error…
    …maybe use the return value in vp…
}
```

**`sorter.c`**

```
static pthread_t thread1;
static void *sorter_thread(void *arg);

void sorter(void)
{
    if (pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, sorter_thread, NULL) != 0)
        …handle error…
}

void sorter_join(void)
{
    void *vp = 0;
    if (pthread_join(&thread1, &vp) != 0)
        …handle error…
    …maybe use value in vp…
}
```

**`main.c`**

```
#include "sorter.h"
#include "network.h"

int main(void)
{
    network();
    sorter();
    network_join();
    sorter_join();
    return 0;
}
```

You would probably build checks into `network_join()` and `sorter_join()` such that if you've not already called `network()` or `sorter()`, the code won't try to join an invalid thread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I apologize that was a typo. I meant to call it network() in the network.c file, the function types also need correcting but i'll re-edit everything so it makes a little more sense and proceed from there.

So with the sorter & network code running (if executed properly), would I be able to connect to the server created, and make calls that are within the sorter.c file (provided I have the internal commands in my network.c file)?

 I'll try this structure out and see where I get.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any issues with this?

It looks like maybe you do not understand what [`pthread_join(thread1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) does.  It does *nothing*, except wait until `thread1` is finished.  But you said that the network thread and the sorter thread are meant to run forever, so that's going to be a long wait:

---

For future reference, `pthread_join()` is meant to be used like this:

```
pthread_create(&thread1, attrs, f, arg);
doSomethingElse(...);
pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
doOtherStuff(...);
```

The original thread starts the new thread, and then it does something else while the new thread is calling `f(arg)`.  Then, after the `f(arg)` call and the `doSomethingElse(...)` call have both completed, the original thread goes on to `doOtherStuff(...)`.